# NeoVim Save BreakPoints to Session

Tags: neovim, sessions, debugging, plugin-vimspector

I am using NeoVim for writing go code, for debugging I am using `vimspector`
The debugging works well, however everytime I exit and restart nvim the breakpoints are lost.
I tried saving the session using `vim-session` but even that does not work.
Is there a way to save the breakpoints in the session, so that the next time I open the project the breakpoints are restored.

Comment: There is no capability of this yet. https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/issues/453

Answer (score 1):

This and more (saving of watch window variables) should now be possible with a [recent commit](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/pull/465) on github.

Essentially, prior to exit, you can have something so:

```
nnoremap <leader>d1 :call vimspector#WriteSessionFile(".vim/debuggingsession.txt")<CR>
```

Then, the next time you are in, you call:

```
nnoremap <leader>d2 :call vimspector#ReadSessionFile(".vim/debuggingsession.txt")<CR>
```